# R ggpubr/ggplot2 use italics for one factor level

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, italic

I would like to create a figure in which one of my factor levels (Bacillus) is italicized.

I have included the way I like to set up my data and how I create my figures -- I just need "Bacillus" to be italicized

```
IF_Eff_2 <- read_excel(("In-furrow x starter trial/2021 In-furrow x starter efficacy.xlsx"), 
                      sheet = "2 yr metric")
IF_Eff_2$Fung <- factor(IF_Eff_2$Fung,
                  levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  labels = c("Fung1", "Fung2", "Fung3", "Bacillus"))
IF_Eff_2$Start <- factor(IF_Eff_2$Start,
                  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                  labels = c("Fert1", "Fert2", "Fert3"))
IF_Eff_2$Rep <- factor(IF_Eff_2$Rep,
                 levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
IF_Eff_2$Year <- factor(IF_Eff_2$Year,
                 levels = c(2020, 2021),
                 labels = c(2020, 2021))
```

```
ggboxplot(IF_Eff_2, x = "Fung",
          y = "RST", 
          fill = "Fung",
          facet.by = "Year",
          ylab = "Sucrose yield (g/kg)",
          xlab = NULL)
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        text=element_text(family="Calibri", size=30),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  border() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(IF_Eff_2$RST), linetype = 2) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(color="black",fill=NA,size=1.5)) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=8, size=5, color="black", fill="black")
```

[This is currently my figure -- I just need Bacillus to be italicized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVhnw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Fung1", "Fung2", "Fung3", expression(italic("Bacillus"))))
```

After your final line `stat_summary(......)`

Comment: Thank you - When I previously tried to do this, I was using scale_fill_brewer earlier in the chunk and an error would occur. It seems that adding scale_fill_brewer as the last line allows it to work.